# Confused about viewmodel creation where I have to add a computed field

Tags: ajax, knockout.js

My json call returns an object array:

```
[
{
Table: 1,
FirstName: "Bert",
LastName: "Smith",
Place: 1
},
{
Table: 1,
FirstName: "Suzanne",
LastName: "Smith",
Place: 2
},
{
Table: 1,
FirstName: "Matthew",
LastName: "Stewart",
Place: 3
},
{
Table: 1,
FirstName: "Brian",
LastName: "Robinson",
Place: 4
},
{
Table: 1,
FirstName: "Jennifer",
LastName: "Robinson",
Place: 5
},
{
Table: 1,
FirstName: "Andrew",
LastName: "Caygill",
Place: 6
},
{
Table: 1,
FirstName: "Susan",
LastName: "Caygill",
Place: 7
},
{
Table: 1,
FirstName: "John",
LastName: "Spreadbury",
Place: 8
},
{
Table: 1,
FirstName: "Anne-Marie",
LastName: "Nevin",
Place: 9
}]
```

I have a template in my HTML:

```
<script type="text/html" id="dataLine">
    <div class="itemLine">
        <div class="Name">
            <span class="fixtureBoxLine" data-bind="text: fullName"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="TableNo">
            <span class="fixtureBoxLine" data-bind="text: Table"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

and the binding is:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'dataLine', foreach: pageCol1 }"></div>
```

My viewmodel is:

```
var viewModel = {
    fields: ko.observableArray([]),
    pageSize: ko.observable(1),
    pageIndex: ko.observable(0)
}; 
viewModel.pageCol1 = ko.computed(function() {
    var size = Number(this.pageSize());
    var start = this.pageIndex() * size * 2; //2 cols per page
    var end = start + size;
    return this.fields.slice(start, end);
}, viewModel);
```

All works fine except I can't get a "fullname" property.  If I try adding it to the viewmodel in the same way as I did with "pageCol1" above, then as my json success property just does:

```
viewModel.fields(xlData);
```

it doesn't work as there is no "fullName" property on the data returned.

I feel I've tried every possible combination today and have now given myself a headache!  Please would someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try extending your `pageCol1` by adding new field (concatenated from another two) to your response array like:

```
viewModel.pageCol1 = ko.computed(function() {
    var size = Number(this.pageSize());
    var start = this.pageIndex() * size * 2; //2 cols per page
    var end = start + size;

    for( var i = 0, len = this.fields.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        this.fields[ i ].fullName = this.fields[ i ].FirstName + ' ' + this.fields[ i ].LastName;
    }

    return this.fields.slice(start, end);
}, viewModel);
```

so in final result before you're iterating over your array it will be like:

```
[
{
Table: 1,
FirstName: "Bert",
LastName: "Smith",
fullName: "Bert Smith",
Place: 1
},
{
Table: 1,
FirstName: "Suzanne",
LastName: "Smith",
fullName: "Suzanne Smith",
Place: 2
},
{
Table: 1,
FirstName: "Matthew",
LastName: "Stewart",
fullName: "Matthew Stewart",
Place: 3
},
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate it *could* be done that way, but I would really appreciate knowing how to extend my viewmodel/javascript to do this if possible?